# Picture environment: line length does not match its coordinates

Tags: diagrams, coordinates

Well I have a problem matching line end with its coordinate. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{picture}(260,210)

\put(0,32){\line(1,0){260}}%
\put(0,32){\circle{2} }%
\put(260,32){ \circle{2} }%

\end{picture}
\label{fig:01}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you can see the second circle isn't placed at the end of a line despite their coordinates should match. Code is pretty simple yet I can't find the reason why the circle and the line are shifted.

Comment: You have a space before the second `\circle` and this space you should remove.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)

Answer (score 2):

---

do not use spaces in the argument of `\put`:

```
\begin{picture}(260,210)
\put(0,32){\line(1,0){260}}
\put(0,32){\circle{2}}
\put(260,32){\circle{2}}
\end{picture}
```

And, by the way, using package `pict2e` makes sense.